# FluentValidation: How to register all validators automatically from another assembly?

Tags: c#, .net-core, startup, registration, fluentvalidation

I'm using "FluentValidation.AspNetCore" library (Version="8.6.2") for a .Net Core project.

What I would like to do is to register all my Validators automatically in Startup.cs class, using something like this (which is what I'm using now):

```
services.AddControllers().AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
```

But the problem is that my validators are going to be moved to another assembly (required by client), so I can't use Startup as reference for the registration.

Is there a way I can do this without having to register the validators one by one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For registering Validator, there are three ways.
>
> 1. Registering each validator in Service with AddTransient.
> 2. Registering using “RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining” method registers all
>    validators derived from AbstractValidator class within the assembly
>    containing the specified type.
> 3. Registering using “RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly” method.

source [here](https://tutexchange.com/how-to-use-fluentvalidation-in-asp-net-core/)

If you use option number 2 and replace `Startup` in your code with any class derived from `AbstractValidator` from another assembly, it will register **all** validators from that assembly

Example:

```
services.AddControllers().AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<AnotherValidationClass>());
```

Comment: Thanks! I left one on the validators I had implemented as reference.

Answer (score 15):

**AddFluentValidation() is deprecated.**

source : https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1965

old:

```cs
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddFluentValidation(fv => { });//or AddMvc(), AddMvcCore()

    //or
    builder.Services.AddFluentValidation(config => 
    {
        config.ConfigureClientsideValidation(enabled: false);
    });
```

new :

```cs
    builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<AnyValidator>() // register validators
    builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation(); // the same old MVC pipeline behavior
    builder.Services.AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters(); // for client side
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [the official nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions) for that:

`services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<SomeValidator>()`;

or

`services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining(typeof(SomeValidator))`;

or

`services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(typeof(SomeValidator).Assembly)`;

All possible DI options described [here](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/di.html)