# In C#, how can I add instances of FluentValidation using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, dry, fluentvalidation, type-safety

Currently, I’m adding validators in the Startup.cs like:

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            Register<Signer, SignerValidator>(builder);
            Register<ContractBase, ContractBaseValidator>(builder);
            Register<ContractGridop, ContractGridopValidator>(builder);
            Register<ContractSepa, ContractSepaValidator>(builder);
            Register<ContractVollmacht, ContractVollmachtValidator>(builder);
        }

        private static void Register<TType, TValidator>(
                ContainerBuilder builder
            ) =>
             builder.RegisterType<TValidator>()
                    .As<IValidator<TType>>()
                    .SingleInstance();
```

It occurs to me:

1. It should not be necessary to pass both `TType` and `TValidator` because every instance of `TValidator` is defined in terms of `TType`.
2. Doing it this way is not only redundant but dangerous because there is no guarantee that `TType`  will correctly correspond to `TValidator`.
3. There should be a way for the system to automatically discover what validators exist and then automatically add them (similar to how the API controllers are being added).

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63023438/fluentvalidation-how-to-register-all-validators-automatically-from-another-asse - also you can solve problem 2 with some type constraints.

Comment: @Jamiec, cheers for the link.  While it certainly helps me improve my solution (I don't know why we are using Autofac), it doesn't completely answer my question.  1. I don't know anything about "Assemblies", so I'm not necessarily trying to add validators from these; and 2. Unless I am missing something, I still need to explicitly add each validator.  I'm wondering if there is a way for the system to just automatically add everything which extends `AbstractValidator`.

Comment: "Assemblies" are just what .NET code gets compiled into (those things ending .exe ort .dll) - and did you read the accepted answer especially this bit `Registering using “RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining” method registers all validators derived from AbstractValidator class within the assembly containing the specified type.`

Comment: I read that, but I'm not entirely clear what to make or do with that since till looking at the other Q/A, I had no idea there was a concept called "Assembly" and now that I know it exists, I'm still far from clear how to make use of it, including how I could get a reference to the current (or concurrent?) assembly to send to a method which might accept it.

Comment: You can use `RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining` with _any_ of your validator classes and it will register _all_ of the others. Refer to the documentation for FV for more info and examples: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#automatic-registration

Comment: @Jamiec, in other words, I need to explicitly name one validator, but I only need to explicitly name the one validator as along as all my other validators exist in the same project and therefore will exist in the same assembly?  There is no way to do the registration without naming any validators at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @Jamiec and a colleague, I now understand all I need to do is:

`services.AddFluentValidation(c => c.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());`

... assuming all my validators live in the same project as Startup.cs